# What's the best way to map a container's host IP to a virtualhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In our rails app, we have a database config file where the database host is set to `MY-DB`.

In our current environments, we simply modify /etc/hosts so that `MY-DB` is mapped to whatever IP address we need (localhost for dev).

`1.1.1.1 MY-DB`

We're containerizing all our services with Docker, and I'd like to keep the database config file the same for now. How do I tell my container to make this mapping? Do I simply copy an /etc/hosts with the desired mapping into the container at buildtime?

I'm using a typical ruby container, ruby:2.2.5.

For the sake of development, I did find [this explanation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds) of `docker.for.mac.localhost`, and if I go ahead and replace `MY-DB` with `docker.for.mac.localhost` directly in the db config, it works as desired, but I'd like to make that mapping in Dockerland instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running your database server on your Mac, and not in a container, you can add the `--add-hosts` flag to `docker run`.

In your case, you could use

```
--add-hosts MY_DB:`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
```

This command is specific to Mac, and would not work in an environment where the host is Linux.

Comment: I also needed to adjust permissions to complete the connection https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175399